# How do I get the global coordinates of a grouped svg element?

Tags: javascript, svg, coordinates

Suppose I have the following [document (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/T8aZP/):

```
<svg>
    <g transform="translate(50,50)">
        <rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:black;">
    </g>
</svg>
```

How do I get the global coordinates of the rect element assuming I don't know that it's in a group?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was actually kind of hard to find. Searching for methods of `SVGElement` results in pages saying `SVGElement` has no methods! It does in fact have a ton of methods, but they are inherited:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable

Depending on what you want you can use the result of `getCTM` or `getScreenCTM` to transform a `SVGPoint`, and thus learn where you element is:

```coffeescript
root = document.getElementById('root')
rec = document.getElementById('rec')
point = root.createSVGPoint()
# This is the top-left relative to the SVG element
ctm = rec.getCTM()
console.log point.matrixTransform(ctm)
# This is the top-left relative to the document
ctm = rec.getScreenCTM()
console.log point.matrixTransform(ctm)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kitsu_eb/ZXVAX/3/

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about matrixTransform. The javascript is empty in your fiddle. Did you update? Trying to test this out.

Comment: I tried thedeeno's linked fiddle, but I didn't get the result I expected. Here is a fork that uses getBBox to set the point's initial coords: http://jsfiddle.net/kitsu_eb/T8aZP/15/

Comment: Apparently SVGMatrix is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGMatrix

Doesn't that make getScreenCTM and getCTM deprecated as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the bounding box. Then, use `height`, `width`, `top` and `left` values to find the center position of your element.

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect