# Interact JS, Drag svg elements inside viewboxed svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, interact.js

My problem, when I drag elements, the element is far behind the cursor, so it looks like it's a ratio issue potentially?

[image: screen grab of the weird movement]

The code:

```
    interact('.element', {
        context: '.lipstick__plane'
    })
        .draggable({
            snap: {
                targets: [
                    interact.createSnapGrid({x: 10, y: 10})
                ],
                range: Infinity
            },
            inertia: true,
            restrict: {
                restriction: '#lipstick__plane__main',
                elementRect: {top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1},
                endOnly: true
            }
        })
        .on('dragmove', function (event) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                var target = event.target,
                    x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('x')) || 0) + ((1020 / window.outerWidth) * event.dx),
                    y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('y')) || 0) + ((1020 / window.outerHeight) * event.dy);

                var indx = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');

                _.set($scope.stage.elements[indx], 'meta.XCord', x);
                _.set($scope.stage.elements[indx], 'meta.YCord', y);
            });
        });
```

I am diving there, which got it closer to the cursor, but i could be trying numbers all day long...

My svg init block:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" width="1024px" height="1024px" xml:space="preserve" id="lipstick__plane__main">
```

One thing I do think could be a problem, but i doubt it, is that the Angular digest happens after a requery to get the new `x` and `y` attribute?

Comment: Have you checked if any transformation is applied within the svg? Looks as if the translation is scaled, what could be caused by a wrapping group which has transform....

Comment: Well there is a `width: calc(100vw - 200px)` applied  to the wrapper div, and a `display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;` to the svg element itself.

Comment: Then it is a scaling issue. Give it a try with the svg appearing with its 1024 pixels in size and it should work. If thats the case you should use the screen transformation matrix to scale the translation vector

Comment: Here is the svg on screen `copy+paste, outerHTML` http://pastebin.com/fNtpjDXm

Comment: @philipp that makes sense, but i need the svg to scale to the correct width, is there a way to run the `dx`, `dy` through an algorithm maybe??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem comes to happen since the inner setup of the SVG is set to 1024 Pixel in width and Height, but displayed in a different Size, smaller in this case, so the applied translation from the drag is scaled down and the element appears to be slower than the cursor.

To address this, you need to scale the translation vector accordingly. One way to gain the scaling factors `sx` and `sy` could be:

1. query the resulting bounding box `bb` of the svg by `getClientBoudingRect`
2. `sx = bb.width / 1024 // (original size), same for sy`

Or, if you can access the `svg` element you can use `.getScreenCTM()` to get the transformation matrix. Which should look like this:

```
| a  c  e |
| b  d  f |
| 0  0  1 |
```

`a` should represent `sx` and `d` `sy`.

**Edit**

I have setup a little fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f5jf0ar4/7/) which shows the basic approach. All in all, the solution is a matrix transformation of a vector and the puzzle to solve is to find the right matrix. Since any svg element may have its own transform, or as child of a group, may gain transform from its parents, it is not sufficient to use the root `<svg>`'s **C**urrent **T**ransformation **M**atrix. That is why each `SVGElement` implements the the [SVGLocatable](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) Interface, what enables you to gain the transform from the root `<svg>` to the `SVGElement` (getCTM), or, the document to the `SVGElement` (getScreenCTM()). The opposite direction is described by the inverse of those matrices. ([explanation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817790/how-do-i-get-the-global-coordinates-of-a-grouped-svg-element))

```
let svg   = document.querySelector('svg'),
    e     = svg.querySelector('.myelement'),
    ctm   = e.getScreenCTM(),
    point = svg.createSVGPoint(),
    point2;

point.x = …;
point.y = …;

point2 = point.matrixTransform(ctm);
```

To conclude: Using the transformation matrix should be the preferred way, since it will (at least should) take all transformations into account, which could be applied to the svg by css, like rotations, 3d transforms and so on. The more specific you are, meaning the more you know the element you would like to transform, the higher the precision will be.

Comment: Once I have this scaling vector, do I use this as the `x += sx` and `y += sy` coordinates of when the mouse moves?

Answer (score 1):

Because your SVG is scaled, your mouse coordinates are not 1:1 with your SVG coordinates.  So you need to convert the mouse/screen coordinates to SVG coordinates in order to get the correct position for the dragged object.

See this question for how to do the conversion.

[How do you convert screen coordinates to document space in a scaled SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183727/how-do-you-convert-screen-coordinates-to-document-space-in-a-scaled-svg)